# Using images with custom formatter and cellEdit in jqGrid cause JavaScript error - solution

Tags: image, jqgrid, formatter

I had a problem in my web application when using jqGrid with editable cells (cellEdit: true in options) and a custom formatter that returned an image based on the cell's value.

When clicking in a cell, that is not on the image itself, cell editing works like a charm. However, when clicking on the image itself you encounter a JavaScript-error claiming that parentNode could not be found.

I have not delved far into the problem, but I guess it has something to do with how jqGrid applies the image using the custom formatter, or how it tries to get the parentNode.

Anyway, by specifying an onclick-event on the image itself that calls its parentNode and clicks it the error is avoided.

For example, an easy custom formatter that circumvents this error is:

```
function booleanFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    if (cellvalue == true){
        return '<img src="checked.png" onclick="this.parentNode.click();"/>';
    }
    else if (cellvalue == false){
        return '<img src="notchecked.png" onclick="this.parentNode.click();"/>';
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

An excerpt of a colmodel that utilizes the formatter could be:

```
colmodel: [ { name: 'CheckableCell', index: 'CheckableCell', editable: true, formatter: booleanFormatter}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or you could accomplish the same result in a more unobtrusive, jQuery-like way. First, change the formatter function as follows:

```
function booleanFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    if (cellvalue == true){
        return '<img src="checked.png" class="imgclickable"/>';
    }
    else if (cellvalue == false){
        return '<img src="notchecked.png" class="imgclickable"/>';
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Next, add this to the properties list of the grid itself (attaches a function to the gridComplete event of the grid):

```
gridComplete: function() {
    jQuery('.imgclickable').click(function() {
        this.parentNode.click();
    });
}
```